# A problem with stopping time about random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk

> Let $(Z_i)_{i \ge 1}$be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables that are uniformly distributed on $\{1,1\}$ i.e., $P(Z_i = 1) = P(Z_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and define the Markov chain, for $n \ge 1$, $X_0 = 0$
>   \begin{equation*}
> X_n = X_{n-1} + Z_n
> \end{equation*}
>   Now, let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a non-zero and define
>   \begin{equation*}
> T = \inf\{n \ge 1: X_n = a\}
> \end{equation*}
>   which is, $T$ is the first hitting time of $a$ and a stopping time

Then, $E[X_T] = 0$ or $E[X_T] = a$?

(1) First, I am not sure $X_T$ is a measurable function, i.e., a random variable.

(2) If so, for all $\omega \in \Omega$, $X_{T(\omega)} (\omega) = a$ and in that case, $E[X_T] = a$. Is this the wrong argument?

(3) However, I think, according to Optimal Sample Theorem and Wald Identities, $E[X_T] = 0$.

I am really confused about this. Could you tell me which part is wrong and what the right argument is? Thank you very much.

Comment: $EX_T=a$ is correct. Wald's identity requires $ET<\infty$ which is not satisfied here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much! Can you show how to show $ET < \infty$. I am pretty unconfident in probability theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $X_T$ is $\mathcal F_T:=\{A\in \mathcal F\mid A\cap\{T=n\}\in \mathcal F_n\}-$measurable.

2) Obviously (and as you remark), $\mathbb E[X_T]=a$ ($X_T$ is deterministic).

3) Why do you think that you can use Optional stopping theorem ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
1) So, $\mathcal{F}_T := \{A \in \mathcal{F}\vert A \cap \{T = n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n, \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$? Also, since $X_T^{-1}(B) = \bigcup\limits_{n \in B} \{T = n\}$,  $X_T^{-1}(B) $ is $\mathcal{F}_T$- measurable?
2) Thank you for clarifying it.
3) The reason was that the same example was in the introduction of Optional stopping theorem during the lecture. However, after explaining the concepts, such as Wald identities etc, the lecture said if $E(T) < \infty$, $E[X_T] = 0$. So, I thought the $T$ in my question had a finite expectation.

Comment: Also, could you recommend me any book or literature which mentions $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable? I think that kind of rigorous book would be very nice. Also, I'd very much appreciate it if you'd show how to show $E[T] < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I was just got stuck at this question so I decided to complete this question for future people who come here.

The reason we can't use Doob's thm is because $\mathbb{E}[T]=\infty$. I will prove it for $a=1$. 
$\mathbb{E}[T]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P(T=k)$
 $\mathbb{P}(T=k)=\mathbb P(S_k=1 \wedge \forall m<k S_m<1)=\frac{C_k}{2^k}$ when $C_k$ is Catalan number. Using Stirling's formula we get
$\frac{C_k}{2^k}\geq\frac{2^k}{k\sqrt k}e^{-\frac{1}{8k}}>\frac{2^k}{50k\sqrt k}$ 
And so 
$\mathbb{E}[T]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P(T=k)>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^k}{50k\sqrt k}=\infty$